# visual studio почему происходит не правильное определение элемента ListView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Необходимо вывести индекс выбранного элемента ListView.SelectIndex по непонятной причине выдает индексы с задержкой, т.е после первого клика он выдает -1(типо ничего не выбрано) при переклике на другой элемент выдает значение первого. Т.е выдает значения предыдущего элемента. Как заставить выдавать его актуальную информацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо события выделения использовать ItemClick событие, и так же в настройках ListView ItemClick поставьте Enabled. На событии клика использоуйте e.ClickedItem - это тот объект, который вы выбрали. Дальше ListViev.Items.IndexOf(e.ClickedItem приведенный к типу объекта)  - вы получите индекс.